# В момент загрузки картинки видим лоадер, затем сразу саму картинку - как сделать на React?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, reactjs

После нажатия на кнопку  "сгенерировать новую картинку" я рандомно выбираю ее id и получаюurl картинки вида 
`images/static/${id}" , где id - id выбранной картинки и рендерю ее. После нажатия на кнопку, нужно чтобы вместо картинки был лоадер. Как только выбранная картинка подгрузилась, лоадер исчез и появилась сразу полученная картинка(не видим процесс ее загрузки. в момент загрузки видим лоадер)
как можно сделать такое поведение на реакте?

Answer (score 1):

В объекте `state` заводите переменную `loading`, когда начинаете загрузку картинки ставите её в `true`, когда картинка загружена ставите `false`.

В `render` функции в зависимости от `this.state.loading` выводите либо загрузчик, либо картинку.

```
{this.state.loading ? <div><img src="loader.gif"></div> :
<div>код вашей картинки</div>
}
```

Но в вашей ситуации можно предложить решение ещё лучше, делать предзагрузку картинки, пока смотришь одну, следующая уже подгружается. Таким образом у пользователя в обычном случае картинка будет отображаться сразу. Загрузчик тоже надо сделать, на случай если картинка всё-же не успела подгрузиться.

Comment: а как отследить что картинка загрузилась? нужно события onLoad у Img?

Comment: @werty `Image` можно грузить через `var img = new Image(); img.src="MyImage.jpg"`, и у `img` есть функция `onLoad`.